# Can not understand tag?

Tags: php, asp.net, asp-classic, tags

I found this form where the input value are populated with variable inside this

```
<%=
```

tag,

what is this tag?

To which programming language does it belong ?

```
<input type="hidden" name=" requestparameter " value="<%= requestparameter %>">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an asp tag that can be enabled in php by setting `asp_tags=1` in `php.ini` file. When enabled,

```
<%
  //php code here
 %>
```

is equivalent to

```
<?php 
  //php code here
?>
```

In this case

```
<input type="hidden" name=" requestparameter " value="<%= requestparameter %>">
```

is equivalent to

```
<input type="hidden" name=" requestparameter " value="<?php echo(requestparameter) ?>">
```

Answer (score 4):

It's an asp parsing tag. It indicates that the value inside should be written to the output. In php these tags can be enabled through a setting.

Comment: "*a setting*" being [`asp_tags`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.asp-tags)

Answer (score 2):

The classic (not .NET) **ASP** (Active Server Page) Server Tag:

```
<%="Text"%> or <%=someVariable%>
```

is a short form for:

```
<% Response.Write "Text" %> or <% Response.Write("Text") %> or 
<% Response.Write someVariable %> or <% Response.Write(someVariable) %>
```

which will output as Text into the HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

that is an [asp](http://www.asp.net/) tag to write the value of a variable